# How to Reposition an Empty Without Moving the Instances inside it?

Tags: parent

I have a car model where the wheel instances are grouped under an Empty.  However, the Empty's position is not at the axis of the wheel where I want it to be for rotating..

Is there a way to position the empty without moving the wheel instances?

Comment: You could unparent them wheels move the empty then parent the wheels again

Answer (score 1):

Thank you - I achieved the desired outcome by unparenting the instances with keep transformations, to reposition the empty, then reparenting the instances with keep transformations.